# How to code sign an XML file for Windows 8 Store apps

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, code-signing

In order to use certain capabilities in Windows 8 Apps (ie documentsLibrary), the developer must EV Code Sign an XML file from Microsoft using SHA2, as per the dashboard information:

> Certain specialized apps can only be submitted from developer accounts
>   which have undergone additional proof of identity verification. This
>   EV status is obtained by downloading and signing an XML file with an
>   EV code-signing certificate. Most developer accounts do not need this
>   additional status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx

> In addition, apps that declare the documentsLibrary capability can
>   only be submitted from developer accounts which can demonstrate they
>   have acquired an Extended Validation (EV) code signing certificate
>   from a certificate authority (CA). EV status is confirmed by
>   downloading and signing an XML file provided by the Windows Store
>   portal with a valid EV code-signing certificate obtained through
>   Symantec or Digicert.

I have the XML file, and a certificate from Symantec, however I cannot find any documentation on how to code sign an XML file. The closest I can find is an article on the symantec website about signtool.exe

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO20528

But when I try to use signtool with Microsoft's XML file I get the error "This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized".

So my question is, how do I sign this XML file with my certificate so I can upload my app to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this tool to sign your xml file: http://www.signfiles.com/xml-signer/ 
Signtool from Windows SDK can only sign binary files, like executables or dlls by adding additional section to the file.

Comment: This worked, only when I tried to upload it to Microsoft they said "Validation error:   You must sign the XML file using SHA2." I can't see a way of using SHA2 with that app.

Comment: I'm stuck at the SHA2 requirement. The app at codesignforxml.codeplex.com has absolutely 0 documentation. It's command line and I've tried running it 10 different ways and the only error output are null reference exceptions.

Comment: I found a way to get this to create a file by installing the user certificate, but then the app store rejects it saying that it is not an acceptable signing method.

Comment: Can a moderator please remove this as an accepted answer? The original answer isn't correct, and even the OP's response to a link for something that does work, isn't working. Either that or it needs more detail on how to use it. Here is another user who is experiencing problem using the app mentioned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388170(v=vs.85).aspx
I'd hate to open a new question when mine is identical to this one.

Comment: @Lawrence Johnson I hope you have a valid certificate?

Comment: Yes, it's a digicert EV that we paid a lot of money for.

Comment: I also get that error, but I believe it is a problem at Microsoft's end. This answer solves the XML issue, I will remove it if it turns out this is indeed the wrong way to sign files for Windows 8 Store.

Answer (score 4):

As [MSDN suggest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx), you should use [Code Signing Tool for Xml](https://codesignforxml.codeplex.com/).

Usage for Token:

```
SignXml.exe TOKEN SHA256 {publicCert.cer} {signable xml}
```

Usage for Pfx:

```
SignXml.exe PFX SHA256 {cert.pfx} {publicCert.cer} {signable xml}
```

If you have no .pfx file and only .pvk, use this tool to convert: `pvk2pfx.exe` (from Windows Platform SDK).

Exmaple: `pvk2pfx.exe -pvk myCertificate.pvk -spc myCertificate.cer -pfx myCertificate.pfx -po pa$$word`

Comment: The EV Cert doesn't come with pfx or pvk. I've been trying the TOKEN usage, which does run without error, but when uploaded, it says that the signing method is not valid. Here's another person with the same problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a7cc17e1-d77e-4b97-b069-37397b9f9ff3/how-to-code-sign-an-xml-file-for-windows-8-store-apps?forum=windowsstore

Comment: Do you have `SafeNet eToken PRO 72K`?

Comment: Did you [install SafeNet](http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/safenet-client-installation.htm) client ?

Comment: Have you exported and used public certificate in .der format?

Comment: I'm using the .der format as the public cert (publicCert.cer)

Comment: Be sure that you have exported the right certificate, not a temporary developer certificate.

Comment: We have. We used the exact format provided above with exception to the fact that SignXml.exe is replaced with CodeSignForXml.exe (because that's the exe it comes with). As mentioned before, the XML file is generated and everything looks great, but then we upload it and the app store says "Validation error:   Signature method of EV certificate is not supported."

Comment: As an FYI to anyone who comes across this, we were able to resolve this issue by having the certificates regenerated as SHA2. They came precompiled from digicert as SHA-1, and even though this is the case, the CodeSignForXml.exe will still allow you to compile as SHA-256 without any warnings. In order to regenerate the tickets, we had to call digicert and have the account reset.

Comment: And to add, the correct usage is the first example in this answer (TOKEN).

Comment: Ahhhr! I'm glad that it work now. However I just started some fun with developing XmlSignChecker :)

Comment: I have the same issue but my cerificate was provided by Symantec, not Digicert.

Comment: Contact Symantec support, they should check your cert and detect if it SHA1 or SHA2(SHA256). Symantec support have an online chat and you can solve it very fast.

Comment: According to Symantec "Unfortunately our EV code signing certificates are only available in SHA1, not SHA2" which is strange because Microsoft specifically says on their site that a cert should be purchased via Symantec or Digicert...

Comment: Do the refund and contact the Microsoft about this issue. They should remove Symantec from the list.